# How to make a button in PHP that deletes the result?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm a novice at this and I just lately dug into the code... I'm having hard time understanding why this doesn't work:

I added a button in the search results so it would delete the certain data field but it doesn't do it.
What am I missing out here?

```
<?php //deleting

isset($_GET['action']) ? $action=$_GET['action'] : $action="";

if($action=='delete'){
$id=$_REQUEST['id'];

$query=mysql_query("set names 'utf8'");
$query = mysql_query("DELETE FROM norse5_proov WHERE id='$id'") or die(mysql_error());

if($query){

echo "<div id='dain'><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>Andmed kustutatud.</div>";

}

}
?>

        <?php //searching
        mysql_query ("set character_set_results='utf8'"); 
        if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
            $query = "SELECT * FROM norse5_proov WHERE 1=1 ";

            if(!empty($_POST["osakond"])){
                $query .= " AND osakond LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["osakond"])."%'";
            }
            if(!empty($_POST["soetusaasta"])){
                $query .= " AND soetusaasta LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["soetusaasta"])."%'";
            }
            if(!empty($_POST["it_number"])){
                $query .= " AND it_number LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["it_number"])."%'";
            }
            if(!empty($_POST["tooteruhm"])){
                $query .= " AND tooteruhm LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["tooteruhm"])."%'";
            }
            if(!empty($_POST["mudeli_nimetus"])){
                $query .= " AND mudeli_nimetus LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["mudeli_nimetus"])."%'";
            }
            if(!empty($_POST["sn"])){
                $query .= " AND sn LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["sn"])."%'";
            }
            if(!empty($_POST["riigivara_nr"])){
                $query .= " AND riigivara_nr LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["riigivara_nr"])."%'";
            }
            if(!empty($_POST["inventaari_nr"])){
                $query .= " AND inventaari_nr LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["inventaari_nr"])."%'";
            }
            if(!empty($_POST["maja"])){
                $query .= " AND maja LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["maja"])."%'";
            }
            if(!empty($_POST["ruum"])){
                $query .= " AND ruum LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["ruum"])."%'";
            }
            if(!empty($_POST["vastutaja"])){
                $query .= " AND vastutaja LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["vastutaja"])."%'";
            }
            if(!empty($_POST["markus"])){
                $query .= " AND markus LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["markus"])."%'";
            }
            if(!empty($_POST["id"])){
                $query .= " AND id LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["id"])."%'";
            }

            ?>
            <table id="tablk">
                <tr>
                    <th width="80">Osakond</th>
                    <th width="80">Soetusaasta</th>
                    <th width="80">IT Number</th>
                    <th width="80">Tooterühm</th>
                    <th width="80">Mudeli nimetus</th>
                    <th width="80">SN</th>
                    <th width="80">Riigivara nr</th>
                    <th width="80">Inventaari nr</th>
                    <th width="80">Maja</th>
                    <th width="80">Ruum</th>
                    <th width="80">Vastutaja</th>
                    <th width="80">Märkus</th>
                    <th width="80">ID</th>
                    <th width="80">Tegevus</th>
                </tr>
                <?php


                $result = mysql_query($query);
                while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo    "<td>".$row["osakond"]."</td>";
                    echo    "<td>".$row["soetusaasta"]."</td>";
                    echo    "<td>".$row["it_number"]."</td>";
                    echo    "<td>".$row["tooteruhm"]."</td>";
                    echo    "<td>".$row["mudeli_nimetus"]."</td>";
                    echo    "<td>".$row["sn"]."</td>";
                    echo    "<td>".$row["riigivara_nr"]."</td>";
                    echo    "<td>".$row["inventaari_nr"]."</td>";
                    echo    "<td>".$row["maja"]."</td>";
                    echo    "<td>".$row["ruum"]."</td>";
                    echo    "<td>".$row["vastutaja"]."</td>";
                    echo    "<td>".$row["markus"]."</td>";
                    echo    "<td>".$row["id"]."</td>";
                    echo "<td>";
                    echo "<button onclick='delete_user( {id} )'>Kustuta</button>"; 
                    echo "<form method='post' action='edit.php?id=<?php echo ".$row["id"]."; ?>'><input type='submit' value='Muuda'>";
                    echo "</td>";

                    echo "</tr>";
                }
                mysql_free_result($result);
                ?>
            </table>
            <?php
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: there is no action in the form url

Comment: I think id is a auto_incremented number and you behave it like a string. Remove the surrounding ' cahrs.

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
echo "<button onclick='delete_user( {id} )'>Kustuta</button>";
```

creates a button and calls `delete_user` function, but it is not PHP function but Javascript. You probably did not define this function. Secondly the problem might be in `{id}`, perhaps you should have written `delete_user(".$row["id"].")`.

I suppose you have to create a button that will submit form that is for deletion. You may want to have two forms, one that is for editing (you have it in the next line), the other for deletion.

Instead of the line I cited use:

```
echo "<form method='post' action='edit.php?action=delete&id=".$row["id"]."'><input type='submit' value='Muuda'>";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<form method='post' action='edit.php?id=<?php echo ".$row["id"]."; ?>
```

The above line is opening a PHP tag within a PHP string.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
echo "<button onclick='delete_user(".$row[id].")'>Kustuta</button>"; 
echo "<form method='post' action='edit.php?action=delete&id=<?php echo ".$row["id"]."; ?>'><input type='submit' value='Muuda'>";
```